Eigenvalues of tridiagonal matrix with linearly growing coefficients
I would like an analytic expression for the eigenvalues of the tridiagonal matrix with linearly growing coefficients
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 2 \\
 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
&& 3 & \ddots & \ddots \\
&& & \ddots & \ddots & n-1 \\
&& & & n-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for any finite $n$, or an approximate expression for large $n$.
I assumed one approach is to compute the characteristic polynomial, and I got the recursion relation:
$$f_n=-x f_{n-1}-(n-1)^2f_{n-2}$$
$$f_1=-x$$
$$f_2=x^2-1$$
where $f_n$ is the characteristic polynomial of the upper block of size $n$.
But I'm not sure what to do past there. Any ideas ?

Perhaps compute $f_3$ and $f_4$ as well? We might spot a pattern

Searching for coefficients in OEIS suggests you might be looking for Meixner polynomials: https://oeis.org/A094368

@ChrisLewis awesome! i didn't know the existence of OEIS
